Maximizing number of passwords over number of unique symbols
Suppose we have an alphabet of size $s$ and are making a password of length $n$. What's the $k$ that maximizes the number of passwords of length $n$ with $k$ distinct characters?
If we know $k$, we can calculate this as if we were first choosing the $k$ out of all $s$ characters, ordering them in any way, and then assigning the $n$ spots to $k$ buckets so they're all nonempty. This is given by $$\binom{s}{k}\cdot k!\cdot S(n,k)$$
where $S(n,k) = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(-1)^{k-j}j^n}{(k-j)!j!}$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind. What $k$ then maximizes this?

What are the relative sizes of $s$ and $n$?

@GregMartin I didn't really have anything specific in mind, but it looks like when $s$ is too small or too large with respect to $n$, the maximum occurs at $k=\min(s, n)$, which is the highest it can be. For "middle" values of $s$, it's a bit below this.

Maybe use some of these: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229561/111594 approximations for the Stirling numbers. I tried:   https://www.desmos.com/calculator/keziblqofv ($h$ is by the approx in the first link, $g$ is by just using Stirling's approx).
